# Colocar apenas um item por linha num Listbox

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, linq, listbox

meu listbox está colocando dois itens ou mais na mesma linha quando cabe.
Como posso forçar o mesmo a botar um item por linha? segue o código abaixo:

**html**

```
  <asp:ListBox ID="OC02_SERV_SOL"  runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
    DataValueField="COD_SERV_SOLIC" DataTextField="COD_SERV_SOLIC" > </asp:ListBox>
```

**javascript**

```
   $(function () {
        $('[id*=OC02_SERV_SOL]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true

        });

    });
```

**na Classe**

```
     var solic = filtro.Select(x => new { x.COD_SERV_SOLIC }).OrderBy(x => 
       x.COD_SERV_SOLIC).Distinct().ToList();                           

      OC02_SERV_SOL.DataSource = solic;
      OC02_SERV_SOL.databind();
```

[image: Como está exibindo]

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deverás conseguir resolver a situação com CSS apenas.
Deves alterar o display de cada item para `display: block`.

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado!!